# how to mock IamRequest impl class using mockito/powermockito?

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock, powermockito

IamRequestImpl.java

```
public class IamRequestImpl<E> extends IamRequest {
    public IamRequestImpl(Iam iam, String s, String s1, Object o, Class aClass) {
        super(iam, s, s1, o, aClass);
    }
}
```

GcsHelper.java

```
public <T> T getServiceAccountKey(IamRequestInitializer req, Iam iam, String requestString,
            String api) throws IOException {
        IamRequestImpl<String> iamRequestImpl= new IamRequestImpl<String>(iam, HttpMethods.POST, requestString, String.class,
                ServiceAccountKey.class);
        iamRequestImpl.setKey(api);
        iamRequestImpl.setFields(SchedulerConstants.JSON_KEY_FIELDS);
        req.initializeJsonRequest(iamRequestImpl);
        return (T) request.execute();
    }
```

GCSHelperTest.java

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ IamRequestImpl.class, ServiceAccountKey.class})
@Test
    public void testGetServiceAccountKeyOnSuccess() throws Exception{
        IamRequestInitializer mockIamRequestInitializer = Mockito.mock(IamRequestInitializer.class);
        IamRequestImpl<String> mockIamRequestImpl = PowerMockito.mock(IamRequestImpl.class);
        PowerMockito.whenNew(IamRequestImpl.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(mockIamRequestImpl);
        when(mockIamRequestImpl.setKey("apiKey")).thenReturn(mockIamRequestImpl);
        when(mockIamRequestImpl.setFields("apiKey")).thenReturn(mockIamRequestImpl);
        Mockito.doNothing().when(mockIamRequestInitializer).initializeJsonRequest(mockIamRequestImpl);
        spyGCSUtils.getServiceAccountKey(Mockito.any(), Mockito.any(), Mockito.any(), Mockito.any());
    }
```

When Running `testGetServiceAccountKeyOnSuccess` test case facing nullpointerException as `iamRequestImpl` is not mocking.

Comment: This looks like basically a struct, which you shouldn't mock in the first place.

Comment: then how can i write a test case for this scenario?

Comment: Give it real strings and objects, that's how.

Comment: It takes some confidential information like API key etc. which we dont have access as a developer. how can i go ahead in this case?

Comment: Then mock those bits as arguments in the constructor, but don't mock the IamRequestImpl itself.  Or just use entirely fake data, not a real API key but at least a real String object.

Comment: I did the same but still no fruitful result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try by converting `Mockito.any()` to specific `object` as follows.

```
spyGCSUtils.getServiceAccountKey((IamRequestInitializer)Mockito.any(), (Iam)Mockito.any(), Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString());
```

since `getServiceAccountKey(IamRequestInitializer, Iam, String, String)`